# ESXi command to check power supply status?

Tags: vmware-esxi, hp, hp-proliant

I need to check the power suppliers status of an HP ProLiant DL380 by ESXi to create/get a note that informs me if one dies.

By using the command esxcli `hardware ipmi sdr list` i'm getting pretty close to what I want:

> Node-Sensor  Description                                Entity-Instance  Computed Reading  Base Unit    Raw Reading

> 0.3          Power Supply 1 Power Supply 1              10.1             35                Watts        7
> 0.4          Power Supply 2 Power Supply 2              10.2             200               Watts        40
> 0.5          Power Supply 3 Power Supplies              10.3             0                 unspecified  0

I get a table of just everything, but i want just one of them. So I tried the `--node=<str>` option (because the table header is "Node-Sensor") without success. How to use it? `--node="0.3"` returns the very same table again.

The same applies to `esxcli hardware ipmi sel list` where I can't figure out how to get a specific event.

Sadly I don't have hpssacli (ssacli only) which seems to have the functions I need.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a Gen8, Gen9 or Gen10 server?

If so, you can configure your ILO to send hardware alerts and status via email.